# y-axis in bar graph ggplot2 plotting incorrectly

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, yaxis

**I am trying to make a simple horizontal bar graph and the y-axis scale seems to be off (see picture). Any pointers are appreciated**

```
L<- data.frame(Language=c("Eng(P) and Spa(S)","Spa(P) and Eng (S)","Eng-only","Spa-only"), Percent=c("53","27","10","10"))
L$Language <- factor(L$Lang, levels = rev(unique(L$Language)), ordered=TRUE)
L$Language<-as.factor(L$Language)
L1<-ggplot(data=L, aes(x=Language, y=Percent, fill=Language)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +  
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") + scale_y_discrete(name="Percent")+
  scale_x_discrete(name="",limits= L$Language) + theme(text = element_text(family="Calibri",size = 14))+theme(axis.text = element_text(family="Calibri",size = 12))
L1 + coord_flip()
```

horizontal bar graph with incorrect y-axis scale

[image]

Comment: You're plotting a character vector instead of numeric; try `Percent=c(53,27,10,10)`

Comment: thank you so much, that worked perfectly!